# Can user variables be assigned of BIT datatype?

Tags: mysql, sql

Based on the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html):

> User variables can be assigned a value from a limited set of data types: integer, decimal, floating-point, binary or nonbinary string, or NULL value.

As you see, user variables aren't supported `BIT` datatype. Right? Ok, I have this code:

```
BEGIN
    SELECT active INTO @active FROM users WHERE id = new.user_id;
    IF (IFNULL((@active & b'100' > 0), 0) < 1) THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = "You cannot vote";
    END IF;
END
```

**Note:** `active` column is `BIT(10)`.

You know, my code surprisingly works as well .. Why? I mean how MySQL treats with `@active` variable as a `BIT` datatype?

Comment: Before 5.0.3, BIT is a synonym for TINYINT(1), which is just a very small integer

Comment: @vol7ron Well I don't use an old MySQL version. I use `Server version: 5.6.21 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)`

Comment: Just saying BIT is more of a simple numeric datatype, it's not like date, json, or spatial, which are more complex.  My guess is even though it's not listed, that boolean values are also acceptable.

Comment: Values will be casted to fit the needs. You can not declare a variable as `bit(10)`, but you can assign a `bit(10)` column to a variable (of both numeric and binary types). It's like the possibility to use both `select * from table where id = '1'` and `select * from table where id = 1` equally. Mysql will just cast the variable and the column value wherever possible. But your variable IS not a `bit(10)`-value, try e.g. a `select @active, active from users`.